# Ghost user processes that restart?

Tags: windows-10, process, users

So, I have a home version of Win10. There's an admin account and then user accounts for the family. When I log in to my account as an ordinary user and view the processes via taskmanager it shows that another **user is "disconnected"** in the status but their account is **using 0.1-0.3% CPU and about 300MB of memory**. The user hasn't logged on since boot and there are no remote sessions.

**Why do these processes start, can I stop them?**

When, for example in **procexp64**, I try to kill the processes it *seems* they will **all end except `sihost`**, if you kill that one Windows starts all the other processes up and a new copy of sihost too.

Any way to get MS Windows to behave? Is this normal or do I have malware??

Windows Defender scan reports nothing and VirusTotal returns 0 hits on any of the running processes (but perhaps there are other hidden processes?).

A consequence of this is that when shutting down, having only logged in one user, windows doesn't proceed with the shutdown request but instead stalls waiting for confirmation as "someone else is still using this PC" or somesuch; obviously no one else is using it as the only user to log in is the one logging out. You can "shutdown anyway" but if you're not paying attention and leave Windows to log itself off then it can hang waiting for the confirmation.

Thanks.

[image: procexp64 output]

Comment: From the admin user (at least to start), scan with Malwarebytes, but do not restart when done. Start Process Explorer, look under the Explorer heading (left side) for processes with Alphanumeric labels. Kill these, exit, restart and test.

Comment: "Any way to get MS Windows to behave?" - It sounds like you want to log out of the user instead of switching users.  Windows is behaving itself.  What you describe is perfectly normal.

Comment: The user that owns the "ghost" processes never logs in, from clean boot, logging in as userA there are processes started for userB (both ordinary users) that use 300MB of memory. How is that perfectly normal? Why don't all user accounts do the same if, as you claim, this is normal? Could you please direct me to where it's documented which processes start and what they're doing, thanks.

Comment: So i f you log is as UserA, you see ghosts frorm USrB & vece-versa? Or is it just one account. Have you tried safe mode? I'm thinking it might be some rogue Sceduled Task...

Comment: Try in *Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options* to turn off "Use my sign-in info to automatically f‌inish setting up my device and reopen my apps after an update or restart", then reboot.

Comment: Can you switch to process tree view in Process Explorer to check the parent process (and parent of the parent and so on) of sihost.exe?

Comment: @pbhj you haven't told us which processes are the rogue ("other user 'B'") ones so we can't obviously explain. Microsoft has a lot of information, its unlikely what you're wanting is on a single articles/site. Their DevCenter tells the inner workings of Windows, but is worded for Developers/Programmers so I don't understand it often. It's also entirely possible they don't explain it because its proprietary & because it might help hackers attack something knowing exactly how it works

Comment: @gregg I've been trying to catch it, the last couple of weeks when I've booted the issue hasn't been present (I only use this computer about 3 times a week; others use it daily). Today, from a fresh boot I caught it: https://ibb.co/f4Z2W25 . The user that has not logged on is using more memory than the user that has (my regular user account). I ran taskmgr as admin, right clicked the username and did "sign off" (can't recall exact command), which freed the 1.2G. Notice there is network activity too, which is troubling.

Comment: @pbhj those processes all seem safe to me, firefox is the one gobbling RAM/memory. John suggested a malwarebytes scan, I'd suggest that at least, maybe Windows Defender & an offline antivirus scan too. Startup items, services, & Task Scheduler can all possibly run scripts so I'd start looking there. Might want to start thinking about doing a Windows reset (kb17085) or a total fresh install

Comment: It's not so much what's running, it's why. Sure FF doesn't look worrying, but how's it even starting when the user hasn't logged in. I've used sysinternals Autoruns, Defender. Doesn't appear to be malware, seems to be Win10, but I can't find any documentation on it ... hence the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a report noting that Win10 works differently when turning-off and then on to what it does when restarting.

This appears to be what's happening, Windows makes ghost processes for the previous user presumably so when that user logs in login is faster; but our use (3 users in sequence) means these processes are always wasted.

To prevent them one can reboot (but turning off-then-on causes them to be made). The processes are always started for the previous user before the computer was turned off.

Corollary to this is to get a clean restart on Win10 one must restart, not power-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly believe this is likely normal & indicative of either Windows background processes or background processes related to another app you have installed. You can likely disable & kill a lot of Windows processes without ill effect that YOU notice, but be warned as they have their purpose even if you don't notice (ex: turn off GPS would cause navigation to break which you may never use or be aware its broken)